# SQL Server Connection Unavailable in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I'm hoping this is a easy/quick fix, but it is taking it's toll on me.

When I try to create a new Data Source in Visual Studio 2010 (Visual Basic) I do not have the option to select "Microsoft SQL Server" in the data source when I click on "Add New Connection" on the Database Explorer.

It will only let me create a connection to a SQL Server Database File. That is NOT what I want.

I want for something like this to show up:

[sample of the data sources i should have http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-76-22/4274.2.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-76-22/4274.2.png)

But I only get the "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" option.

How do I enable to connect to an actual Microsoft SQL Server?

**Also:** I do have this option enabled on Visual Studio Web Developer. Just not on the Visual Basic end and I don't know I did anything for that to show up.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Govind. It seems this is simply a (lack of) feature of the VS2010 express. I installed VS2012 and the option is there. I recently upgraded to Windows 7 so I was able to do the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Install .net data provider if you did not install right provider.
If you have installed everything correctly, then follow the below steps,

There are multiple machine.config files in your \Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\vXXXX\Config directories.  Check both of the v2 and v4 machine.config files for the following (four files total you're looking at here).

There was an EXTRA, self terminated  tag in two of my files.  I had all four open at once comparing them, and noticed in two of them, the V4 I believe, but check them all.  Essentially it was like this and very easy to miss:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" ... />
        <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" ... />
        <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
        <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
        <add name="IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider" invariant="IBM.Data ... />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" ... /></DbProviderFactories>
    <DbProviderFactories/>
</system.data>
```

Notice the CLOSING tag at end of the  last item, in this case the "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider", and then there's another SELF CLOSING  tag.  Clean this up by keeping the one after the last item and deleting the self closing one at the end and then reboot it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this didn't work for me. I have the .NET framework properly installed. It is even available (as I mentioned above) on Visual Studio Web Developer. But not on Visual Basic! I don't understand why?  This is frustrating. I can't seem to get around it.

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server in your machine?

Comment: Not on my machine. I do have SQL Management Studio. The SQL Server it's installed on the server I want to connect to.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22           go this link and download the .net framework 4.0 data provider for sql server and install it.. It may solve your problem.